# How to insert a new user into a database with a hashed password

Tags: mysql, sql, database, insert

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `admin` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `username` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
  `image` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `type` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `date` date NOT NULL,
  `add_date_time` datetime NOT NULL,
  `last_modify` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `stutus` int(2) NOT NULL,
  `last_login` datetime NOT NULL,
  `last_logout` datetime NOT NULL,
  `login_status` int(2) NOT NULL,
  `website_logo` varchar(10000) NOT NULL,
  `transaction_pwd` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `username` (`username`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=5 ;
```

---

This a project am given to work on, my client doesn't want to change the structure of the sql, the sql is storing a hashed password, when i insert a new user with a non-hashed password (normal Password), the created account with the normal password won't login, so please help me on how i can insert a new user with the hashed password (maybe the new user will be able to login. Thanks in Advance

Comment: your table is just storing a varchar string as a password. The code you provided is not related to hashing the password (that is somewhere in your PHP). Please provide the relevant code

Comment: Give the Hash algorithm also please

Comment: @leilo according to what i know, when building a CMS, the admin details are inserted using the insert option then details are updated later, now to my issue, i want to add a new admin but when i insert all the required details including the normal password, when i try to login with the normal password i created i doesn't work